# Adding a DHCP server to an existing network

Tags: windows, networking

I have a network with a few subnets one of which i would like to have DHCP for. Is it possible to just add a DHCP server and have the clients use that. Will it have any impact on other servers on my network?

Comment: **1)** Are the subnets in physically separate broadcast domains (e.g. via separate switches or VLANs) and traffic routed between them? Or are the nodes all in the same broadcast domain but manually placed in separate subnets due to their IP configuration? **2)** Do you have any DHCP servers currently installed? If so, where in relation to the subnets?  **3)** What specifically are you concerned about regarding "impact to other servers"? Performance? Their IP configuration? Something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A DHCP server responds to network broadcasts from devices that have not yet been assigned an IP Address or Subnet Mask. Thus there is no way for a DHCP server to limit itself to a subnet as the devices it will be responding to are assumed not to be in *any* subnet (yet).

There are other ways to limit it... such as with a Layer 2 VLAN which allows you to segment the network in such a way that blocks DHCP broadcasts from propagating between VLANs.

You could also configure your DHCP server to only respond to specific MAC addresses. This will work if:

1. There are no static IP assignments in the IP range the DHCP server is responsible for.
2. There are no other DHCP servers responsible for IP addresses in the same range.
3. Your DHCP daemon supports limiting DHCP responses by MAC address.
4. There are no other DHCP daemons listening and responding to the devices with those MAC addresses.

If you have no other DHCP servers on the network then the most likely result of a poorly (default) configured DHCP server being added to a network full of devices using static IP addresses is that the DHCP server may assign IP addresses to dynamic clients that are already in use by static clients... resulting in an IP address collision.

If you do have other DHCP servers on the network then the most likely result of a poorly (default) configured DHCP server being added to the network is well... "real wrath of God type stuff, rivers and seas boiling, 40 years of darkness, earthquakes, volcanoes, the dead rising from the grave, human sacrifice, dogs and cats living together, mass hysteria!" The only thing predictable about the results is that unpredictable parts of your network will very unpredictably stop working correctly only to very unpredictably start working again while other parts stop. Baaaad juju. Do not do this.

Comment: Great answer, but I don't think you can say DHCP belongs to layer 7. I think it belongs to layer 3, the network layer.

Comment: Really? I thought it was application layer (layer 7).

Still, a layer 2 VLAN will block it for sure. I _think_ a layer 3 VLAN will as well. ::goes to research::

Comment: Hmm, maybe you're right.

Comment: Yeah, everything I'm reading says it's layer 7. :-/

Comment: DHCP definitely does not provide layer-3 functionality like IPv4/IPv6 would. You could place it anywhere between L3½ and L7 though, depending on day of week. (The OSI model was never made with Internet protocols in mind... The concept of an application layer protocol that autoconfigures network layer is completely foreign to OSI stack.) That said, yes, VLANs at L2 will definitely work, and are used by practically all larger LANs for this purpose. "L3 VLANs" won't, as they depend on L3 (IP) addresses being present, while DHCP is broadcast.

Comment: Updated answer to corrected info. ty.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I think in one network only can have one DHCP server. but you can set different VLAN and then in different VLAN you can have one DHCP server. All VLAN in same network.

Comment: This is untrue. Multiple DHCP servers can co-exist on a network. DHCP servers can be configured to discriminate between clients based on a variety of factors. So for example you could have one DHCP server hand out leases to IP Phones while another serves all other client types.

Answer (score -1):

Don't do this, this will definitely have impact on the other servers on your network.

Comment: He asked: Will it have any impact on other servers on my network?

Comment: While this is an *attempt* to answer the question, to avoid downvotes it's necessary to explain why this answer is correct. As written it's an assertion without any evidence to back up that claim.